# It's advertised = It was advertised?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Can I say/write 
"It's advertised" instead of "It was advertised"

Comment: In relaxed/colloquial speech, some speakers wouldn't enunciate the /w/ in, say, *"It was common in ancient Greece"*, but there would invariably be at least a *hint* of a [schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) after the /t/ (which in my idiolect would almost always be reduced to a [glottal stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop) in such contexts anyway). However, the *orthographic* representation ***it's*** is never used for ***it was***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is a contraction that can be used for `it is` or `it has` only.

For instance, the sentence, "It is advertised as a slimming drug," can be written as, "It's advertised as a slimming drug."

Similarly, the sentence, "It has been advertised as slimming drug," can also be written as, "It's been advertised as a slimming drug."

You cannot use this contraction for "it was".

Hope this helps.

PS: If you need a dictionary reference, here it is: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/it%27s